# Symmetric matrix diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we get an invertible matrix $W \in$ $\mathbb{R}$$^{3\times3}$ to make $W\hspace{-1mm}AW^{T}$ a diagonal matrix? Here,

$$ 
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 1 & 3 \\
    1      & 0 & 1  \\
    3      & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

I try to compute the eigenvalues of $A$, but it is difficult to factor the polynomial $t^3 - 5t^2 - 5t - 1 = 0$. I've also attempted to compute its SVD, but the polynomial becomes more complicated. 
Do we have other ways to solve it?

Comment: As Lord Shark the Unknown mentioned, you don’t need the eigenvalues to diagonalize this matrix. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388421/265466.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to find the eigenvectors if you insist that $W$ must be orthogonal.
Basically here we are completing the square. First we find a matrix
$$M=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\*&1&0\\*&0&1}$$
such that
$$MAM^T=B=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&*&*\\0&*&*}.$$
We can take
$$M=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\-1/2&1&0\\-3/2&0&1}$$
and then
$$B=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&-1/2&-1/2\\0&-1/2&-3/2}.$$
Now, we seek a matrix
$$N=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&*&1}$$
to make $NBN^T$ diagonal. Then $W=NM$ suffices.